# chai.request is not a function while using request js for http service unit test

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, karma-runner, chai, requestjs

I have been using karma+requestjs + mocha + chai and sinon. i have been using chai-http module yet receives chai.request is not a function.please suggest where i am making mistake i have googled lot no luck yet.

```
(function() {
  var specFiles = null;
  var baseUrl = '';
  var requirejsCallback = null;
  if (typeof window != 'undefined' && window.__karma__ != undefined) {

    baseUrl = '/base';
    requirejsCallback = window.__karma__.start;
    specFiles = [];
    for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
      if (window.__karma__.files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
        if (/.*\/js\/spec\/.+_spec\.js$/.test(file)) {
          specFiles.push(file);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  requirejs.config({
      baseUrl: baseUrl,

      paths: {
        'chai': './node_modules/chai/chai',
        'sinon': './node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon',
         'chaihttp': './node_modules/chai-http/dist/chai-http',
      },

      deps: specFiles,
      callback: requirejsCallback
  });
})();


**Spect-Test.js**

 define(['chai', 'sinon', 'chaihttp'], function (chai, sinon, chaihttp) {

        var expect = chai.expect;

          describe('Service', function () {

              it('abctest', function () {
                  var abccode = { "abc": "1" };
                  var url = 'http://localhost:1234';
                  chai.request(url)
                      .post('test/testService')
                      .send(abccode )

                      .end(function (err, res) {
                          if (err) {
                              throw err;
                          }
                          expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
                          done();
                      });

             });

        });
    });
```

**Error**
TypeError: chai.request is not a function
            at Context. (

Comment: may be you missed the line `chai.use(chaiHttp)` ...

Comment: @mido i tried  chai.use('chai-http') but now gives hrome (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR: TypeError{}

Chrome  (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.029 secs / 0 secs)

Comment: var chai = require('chai');
    var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
    var expect = chai.expect;
    var should = chai.should;  chai.use(chaiHttp);                                                                                      Module name "chai-http" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])(…)

Comment: `var chai = require('chai'), chaiHttp = require('chai-http'), chai.use(chaiHttp);` now `chai.request(server)...` worked for me

Answer (score 8):

As per mido's comment on this question, using `chai.use(chaiHttp)` worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

You should add this at the beginning:

```
var chai = require('chai'), chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

chai.use(chaiHttp);
```

Comment: i have done this exactly, works fine with typescript but doesnt run for transpiled js. It gives the same error after build

Answer (score 4):

I got the problem but to solve it I checked what is in the chai library (using console.log) and I found that the request function is under default node.

```
import * as chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

chai.use(chaiHttp);

//Parse the assertion library to get the request function as chai.request is not found
let chaiLib = <any>chai;
let chaiRequestLib = chaiLib.default.request;
```

chaiRequestLib can be used then.

```
  return chaiRequestLib(server).post('/api/product')
    .send(product)
    .then((res: any) => {
      res.should.have.status(200);
      res.body.should.be.a('object');
      chai.assert.equal(res.body.affectedRows, 1 , '"Dexeryl Cream 250g" product not created');
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this import method, it worked for me

```
import app from '../../server'
import chai from 'chai'
import chaiHttp = require('chai-http')
import 'mocha'
const expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(chaiHttp);
```